# Adding number of Swing controls based on a user input

Tags: java, swing, dynamic, label

I have form 1 which has a combo box with values 1 to 5 and a Jbutton. when i click this button then form 2 opens up. now in form 2 dynamically the number of labels to be added depends on the value chosen in form 1's combo box. (example if the value of combo box is 3 and then the button is clicked then form 2 will will open with 3 labels)
The article in link :- [How can I dynamically add controls to a form based on JComboBox selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10614151/how-can-i-dynamically-add-controls-to-a-form-based-on-jcombobox-selection)
does not answer the question so posting my question. Please help me getting the solution.

Comment: what result are you getting?

Comment: It sounds like you're working on an existing code base you're trying to debug.  Please post a Simple, Self contained, Correct example demonstrating the problem ( http://www.sscce.org/ ).  It'd very difficult to help you in such a specific problem without an SSCCE.

Comment: How does the previous question not solve your problem, what's missing?

Comment: @NickRippe..yes its part of a bigger problem which i am stuck into.. framing my problem into the best possible and shortest manner is what i tried doing..in short i want "X" number of labels and text boxes placed in a jFrame form. the value of "X" comes from the previous form. i have code where i can place "labels+text boxes" by clicking a button but that is not sloving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I consider you have a container, in which your labels are placed in. So you call a method to show up the second form. This is where you can place your hook: just create a Method in your second form, which takes the selected number as a parameter:

```
public void showUp(int selectedNumber){
   container.clear();
   for(int i = 0; i < selectedNumber; i++){
      conainer.add(new JLabel(i+""));
   }
   form.setVisible(true)
}
```